# Closing an application with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

This is really dumb but I just can't find it online. I have opened an application with Ubuntu. Now I want to close it but I can't see how. I know it is a simple click someplace ... can someone tell me how?

I'm using version 16.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a button on the top left to close the application. You could press `Ctrl+W` or `Alt+F4` to close the application, aswell.

Comment: Found the button. I didn't know it won't show up until you move the cursor to the upper left.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can open the system monitor which is like the task manager in windows. In there select the program you want to close and klick on kill process.